# Angular 8: page redirect to home when refresh base url

Tags: angular, routes

In my angular project i have a menu dashboard , when login it redirects to dashboard but when i remove that dashboard from URL (i.e)before localhost:4200/dashboard, after removed localhost:4200, when refresh how to i navigate to dashboard again?

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' ,pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Comment: Can you share your router config?

Comment: { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' ,pathMatch: 'full'}

Comment: make a **stackblitz** example https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: what is happening when you refresh with `localhost:4200` where is your dashboard route located?

Comment: when you give localhost:4200 in the url does it goto the login component?

Comment: no it shows empty page

Comment: @Harifrais I have updated the answer. Let me know if that works

Comment: Hi all, issue solved i have some thing done in dashboard component /* const routes: Routes = [
    Home.childRoutes([
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            children:[
                { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
            ]
        }
    ])
]; */

Comment: i have commented this now issue solved

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/router#the-default-route-to-heroes

You can change your router config something like below,

```
RouterConfig = [
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard'},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

Add this in your router config and it should work as expected.

Basic routing example => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-11fgob

Comment: but still its not redirect to dashboard it shows empty page when click dashboard only it redirects

Comment: Can you create a simple stackblitz for this? @Harifrais

Comment: Hi @Harifrais I have updated the answer. Can you try this one?

Comment: @Harifrais Removing pathMatch: 'full' doesn't work?

Comment: yes pathmatch: 'full' not worked.it shows empty page after refresh

Comment: @Harifrais That's weird! Please refer the stackblitz and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirectTo`

[According to the Angular documentation for the default routing](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-default-route)

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' ,pathMatch: 'full' }
```

This route redirects a URL that fully matches the empty path to the route whose path is `'/dashboard'.`

After the browser refreshes, the `router` loads the `DashboardComponent` and the browser address bar shows the `/dashboard` URL.

Comment: added this but still not working when refresh localhost:4200 it shows empty page only

Comment: can you please update the question with latest changes in route file, as you need to remove 

`{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }`

Comment: where is the portion of code which I have given, haven't added yet?

Comment: you should import the dashboard component in the imports as well, have you done that?

Comment: yes i have imported the same as well but still not worked

Comment: can you `console.log('test')` in `dashboard component` and check if it is loaded?

Comment: consoled value coming when login as well as click home but refresh(localhost:4200) not coming

Comment: can you change `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },` to `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },` and check,

 `redirectTo: 'dashboard'`

Comment: both are same then why i have to change?

Comment: both are not same, I removed the `'/'` infront of dashboard

Comment: then it should be some authentication guard somewhere, the points I have given should be in `app routing` which is the main module, I hope those are in app module routing itself

Comment: i have put those in app.routing.ts which is main file

Answer (score 0):

Change your router config as below.

```
  import { DashboardComponent} from '..path to your dashboard component';
  import { LoginComponent } from '..path to your login component';

  const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard' ,pathMatch: 'full'} 
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  ]
```

Comment: @Harifrais Is DashboardComponent has any content? Can you please check whether  DashboardComponent is loading by using your browser's developer tools. In developer tools under the network tab, check that your '/dashboard' is loading or not by refreshing.